# Inter-fragment communication applied to Nested Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The Android developers site has a [great article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) on how to use interfaces to communicate between:

1. A `Fragment` and its hosting `Activity`
2. Two `Fragment`s hosted by the same `Activity`

I am struggling to apply this concept to **nested fragments**. In particular, `getActivity()` or `Fragment#onAttach(Activity)` tell you what `Activity` is hosting a `Fragment`.

What is the equivalent in case of nested fragments? How does a "child" `Fragment` know what "parent" `Fragment` it is included in? And without knowing this, how can a child `Fragment` pass events up to its parent `Fragment`?

An obvious way is to broadcast intents from the child `Fragment` and have the parent `Fragment` listen for the broadcast, but I'd rather use the `interface`-based approach.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It turns out there is a [getParentFragment()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment%28%29) method introduced to cater to nested fragments. It is available on `android.app.Fragment` from API 17, but can be used on older versions using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

I can't believe I overlooked this API!

### EDIT:

I came across [this gist](https://gist.github.com/keyboardr/5455206) that makes this process of figuring out the parent component (whether `Fragment` or `Activity`) easy, elegant and safe!

Comment: Yep, getParentFragment() is the way to go if one fragment is inside another. If you want to make fragments at the same level of nesting talk to each other (i.e. get 2 child fragments to talk to each other), use getTargetFragment() and setTargetFragment()