# DialogFragment versus an Activity themed as a Dialog?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-theme, android-dialogfragment

If I want to display a Dialog with some custom XML, I can use a DialogFragment.

However I can also use an Activity instead and give it a Dialog theme, which is convenient because Activities can talk to each other whereas fragments cannot, which makes communication a little easier.

Is there any good reason why I shouldn't be doing it this way? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 3):

> If I want to display a Dialog with some custom XML, I can use a
>   DialogFragment.

Yes we can define the layout in onCreateView() template method callback of DialogFragment.onCreateView() for defining custom layout.

> However I can also use an Activity instead and give it a Dialog theme,
>   which is convenient because Activities can talk to each other whereas
>   fragments cannot, which makes communication a little easier.

1. Yes you can set the same them for activity to make it appear like
   a dialog.
2. For two activities(A & B) to communicate with each other you have to
   use`startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int reqCode)`method which
   start `Activity B from Activity A`. When `Activity B` finishes you
   have to pass result to `Activity A` via `setResult(int reqCode,
   Intent intent)` method.
3. For activity and fragment communication we have to use `Interface`
   driven implementation and its very easy as compare to communication
   between `Activites`. Please checkout following [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for details.
4. Two `Fragment` on same activities can easily communicate with each
   other via `Interface`. Please check above link for details. For
   `Tablet UI` we have to use fragment to make implementation
   manageable and modular.

> Is there any good reason why I shouldn't be doing it this way? What are the pros and cons?

1. If you stick with Activity driven development then porting same
   codebase to tablet is very difficult.
2. If you use fragment for
       small-small functionality your codebase will be modular.
3. Two way communication is possible between `"Fragment & Activity"`
   and `"Fragment & Fragment via Activity"`
4. For `Activity B` to `Activity A` communication `Activity B` will
   destroy and pass its result to `Activity A`.
5. `Activity.startActivityForResult()` has its own advantage. Like if you want to capture a image via camera then we use `Implicit Intent` to start camera `Activity` and once it captures the image it passes URI of image back in `setResult(int reqCode, Intent intent)` and hence calling activity `onActivityResult()` gets invoked so that it can check URI details of image.

Comment: `Two Fragment on same activities can easily communicate with each other via Interface.` They can communicate with each other through the underlying activity, but this becomes messy if you're going from Activity -> Fragment -> Fragment because now you have to start gutting implementation details from the fragments and put them into the Activity, resulting in a ton of bloated code

Comment: @Kalima: You are talking about the case Activity -> Fragment -> Fragment, In this case 2nd Fragment must be nested Fragment mean child of Fragment1. You do not need to communicate to 2nd Fragment directly from Activity. You should pass event to Fragment 1 and then Fragment1 will pass event to Fragment2. Please check following link for details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831690/inter-fragment-communication-applied-to-nested-fragments

Answer (score 1):

DialogFragment is considered as the Android way to display complex dialog. If the only problem you have is communicating with activity or fragment from dialog - there are some simple solutions. One of them - to send a response to an activity from fragment you can use interface. Also, Displaying DialogFragment is faster than launching a new activity. Another advantage for DialogFragment is that passing data from fragment to activity is easier than activity to activity (this requires to put objects as intent extras).